# Building Mockito from source

Tags: java, ant, mockito

I did a git clone of: https://github.com/mockito/mockito

What I am trying to do is to re-package it so the final mockito-core jar will use a modified Objenesis library.

However, I'm a maven user and I am not sure how to deal with making Mockito use my own version of the library and then repackage it with ant. With Maven this is very easy to do just change the `<dependency>` and then `run mvn clean install`

The new Objenesis library is in my local `M2_HOME` maven repository, do I need to manually copy this to the a folder in the `mockito` git directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito's `build.xml` defines a `compile.classpath` that includes all the files in `lib/run` (as well as a couple of other directories). You can change the definition in the build file, or simply replace the jar in `lib/run`.

Having built, installing with the `install.artifact` target will use the pom in `maven/mockito-core.pom`, so you'll need to edit that as well to refer to your modified library.